# Lateral pointers inside Javascript objects

Tags: javascript, oop

I apologize that I don't know of a better way of titling my question--suggestions appreciated.
I know that this is valid:

```
var cyclic = new Object();
cyclic.c = cyclic;
```

and that this doesn't break

```
var cyclic = {c: this};
```

So I was wondering--why doesn't this work?

```
var foo = {a: 10, b: 5, c:(this.a - this.b)};
```

Is it because the elements reference other elements at the same 'level', or that I'm trying to do it all in one step? Is there a way to do this sort of thing in one line?

Comment: `this` isn't the literal object it's the `window`

Comment: `this` depends on how you call a function; there's no function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` doesn't point to what you think it does. When inside a function, `this` will point to the object that function was called on:

```
var o = { foo : function(){ console.log(this); } };
o.foo() // will log o

var o2 = { {bar : {foo : function(){ console.log(this); } } };
o2.bar.foo() // will log o2.bar
```

If the function is not called on any object or if `this` is not inside a function, then it will point to the global object, `window`.

```
var foo = function() { console.log(this); };
foo(); // will log window
console.log(this) // will log window
```

When you do:

```
var cyclic = {c: this};
```

You have created an object named cyclic which has a property c which references the global object.

Similarly, when you do:

```
var foo = {a: 10, b: 5, c:(this.a - this.b)};
```

You create an object with a property which references the a and b properties of the global object.

One thing you could do is create an init function:

```
var foo = { a:10, b:5, init : function(){ this.c = this.a - this.b } };
```

To have `this` be foo, you simply need to call the function as `foo.init()`.

```
foo.init(); // adds the c property to foo, with the value foo.a-foo.b
console.log(foo.c);
```

Comment: I'm glad i could help you, but you should look at the other linked questions which are very similar to yours to find some other ways of dealing with your issue.

Answer (score 0):

`this` isn't the literal object it's the `window` object because you're not calling it with a function.

You could/should utilise a constructor function for this instead,

consider the function below

```
var Foo = function(a, b) {
    this.a = a; //if you want to save state inside the object
    this.b = b; //else skip it.
    this.c = a - b;
}

//create a new object from Foo

var foo = new Foo(10, 5);
foo.c
>> 5
```

Comment: If you have a constructor function (that is called with `new`), do not `return` an object literal!!!